# Are there any good movies/documentaries on programming Applications?

Tags: web, cloud, desktop-application

I am not looking for any inspirational stuff. I am looking for movies which directly speak about the architecture of programming languages, the changes in the architecture which have taken place over the years. Also, I am looking for movies which portray the approach to programming when creating applications for different platforms on web, mobile or desktop.

Answer (score 1):

then you are not looking for a documentary you should be looking for video lectures for eg

For algorithm and programming techniques : http://www.youtube.com/user/BucklandRichard

Programming Paradigms lectures by Professor Jerry Cain in Stanford

But only thing you need to be good at programming is to code try to solve problems

for starters you could try http://www.pythonchallenge.com/

then move on to    http://projecteuler.net/problems

to develop your interests in programming   . 
Best of luck

Comment: The reason I asked for the documentary/movie is because I also want to learn the history, the people, the organizations involved with the advent of above mentioned topics.